# Generate an XML file with ZF2

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework2

I see when i started to learn ZF2 that we can use Zend\Config\Writer to write config in XML and put it into a file. I saw the PhP class DomDocument too. And i saw also SimpleXMLDocument.

I have to make a complex and extremely heavy XML with a lot of data from my Database.
With DOMDocument, for 30% of the work, my code is already too complicated and not maintainable  anymore.

This is a sample of how my XML has to be :

```
//...a lot more XML before
<Lines>
   <line lineNum="Num">

   </line>
   <line lineNum="Num2">

   </line>
</Lines>
//A lot more XML after
```

Those line can be created by a foreach loop. Zend\Config\Writer can't do that (especially for attribute parts) does it ?

**My question is :** 
Is exist a better way that i don't know yet for generate an XML with Zend Framework 2 ?

P.S :I'm looking for Object oriented programming solution.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Use SimpleXML. There is no need for ZF to have an XML component as PHP can do this natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking for an ZF2 internal solution too, @Hooli. Hoping to get some answers on Twitter too:
[What is the best way to generate / write #XML in #ZF2? Make use of \Zend\Feed\Writer or an external class like #SimpleXML? Any known module?](https://twitter.com/webdevilopers/status/466189064044285952)

Maybe one can use the **Zend\Feed\Writer** for these cases as a workaround but I would prefer a ZF2 module or similar.

Otherwise @Tim is right, **SimpleXML** is a good solution. For bigger files *XMLWriter* is recommended.

[Click here for a comparison of the two and DOM](http://p0l0.binware.org/index.php/2011/07/04/simplexml-vs-xmlwriter-vs-dom/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your upvote and your feedback from your searchs. I asked on french zendFramework2 community the same question, i had more feedback and yes SimpleXMLElement is the one i will choose because it's the most flexible and strong solution found yet. I didn't tried Zend\Feed\Writer you can found my discussion here :http://www.z-f.fr/forum/viewtopic.php?id=9075 google translate maybe help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look at the [Zend\Config\Writer\Xml](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Config/Writer/Xml.php#L25) class.

Fortunately an / the **XMLWriter** is already included via PHP Extension!

You can easily inspect the *processConfig* method() and adapt it to your needs. For my use case I even re-used the complete *addBranch* method().

About **XMLWriter**:
[PHP Manual](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/intro.xmlwriter.php)

> This extension represents a writer that provides a non-cached, forward-only means of generating streams or files containing XML data.